# (PHP) If variable is equal to HTML output, do this

Tags: php, jquery, date

I have a script outputting the current day of the week into a HTML span element.

I'd like to find out which day is being inserted into that span element, and show information accordingly. So if "Sunday" is being inserted into the span element, I'd like the text "9AM - 5PM" to be listed. If "Monday" is being inserted into the span, I'd like the text "7AM - 7PM" to be listed. I'll be doing this for each day of the week.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $date = '<span id="date"></span>';
    if ($date == 'Sunday') {
        echo '9AM - 5PM';
    } elseif ($date == 'Monday') {
        echo '7AM - 7PM';
    }
?>
```

I can't get this code to work with me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are setting the value of the `$date` variable to be equal to `'<span id="date"></span>'`. Your if statements conditions will always be false.

Comment: `$date = '<span id="date">Sunday</span>';
 if (strip_tags($date) == 'Sunday') { ... }`

Comment: @adeneo Why bother mocking someone on a site made to help people learn?

Comment: I'm not mocking you, but the way you've explained it to us you're setting a variable to `A`, and on the next line you're expecting it to be `B` or `C`. Either you haven't explained this very well, or it should be rather obvious even to someone with little programming experience why it fails ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i suppose there are several ways to solve your problem (jQuery). But if you want to use Php you could use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. You need to download one php file called simple_html_dom.php you can do that [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and there is manual how to use this in section Download & Documents.

Here is the code for your problem you just need adapt it to suit your files name and location of files.

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('YourHtmlFileName.html');

    $date = $html->find('span[id=date]', 0);

    if($date->innertext = 'Sunday')
        echo '9AM - 5PM';
    else
        echo '7AM - 7PM';
?>
```